# VueJS - Passing data from the created to mounted()

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to pass data from the created function to the mounted function in VueJS. I am building a VueJS application and my created function looks like this,

```
created: function(){
  $.getJSON({
    url: 'static/timeline.json',
    success:function(json) {
      return json;
    }
  })
}
```

I want to pass the json value into vis.DataSet() of my mounted function which looks like this,

```
var items = {};
mounted(){
container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
 items = new vis.DataSet(json);
}
```

So, is there a way using which I can pass data from created to the mounted() function?

Comment: Retrieving your data via `getJSON` is asynchronous. It's highly unlikely the data will be available by the time `mounted` fires. Instead, you should probably move the code you have in `mounted` into your `getJSON` success handler.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically you should. But with your code, you have a problem: asynchronous data. A quick fix should be to move the `vis.DataSet` part into your callback. If for some reason you can't do that, then you'll need to define a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), from which you'll feed the `vis.DataSet`, maybe something like:

```
data: {
    data: null
},
watch: {
    data: function (value){
        vis.DataSet(value || {})
    }
},
created: function(){
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON({
    url: 'static/timeline.json',
    success:function(json) {
      return self.data = json;
    }
  })
}
```